# Why do you need to use the send command to make a timer work in LiveCode

Tags: timer, send, repeat, livecode

from the LiveCode dictionary:

```
# A simple timer using send example

local sTime
on mouseUp
   put 0 into sTime
   send "timerIncrement" to me in 1 seconds
end mouseUp

on timerIncrement
   add 1 to sTime
   put sTime
   send "timerIncrement" to me in 1 seconds
end timerIncrement
```

Why do we have to use the Send command to make this work?

Why can't I do the following to update the label on a card every second?

```
on startTimer
   repeat until lstopTimer is "true"
      updateTimer
      wait 1 second
   end repeat
end startTimer

on updateTimer
   put the long english time into field "time"
end updatetimer
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your repeat loop blocks all other scripts. You would have to add `with messages` to the wait command. A repeat loop with a `wait` command is much more processor intensive then a `send... in time` command. Also, a `send` command allows for more flexibility, because it can be stopped easily by other handlers, using the `cancel` command. Moreover, if a different handler is busy, the `send` command will queue the messages, while a `wait` command will simply block all scripts. Once you get more experience with LiveCode, you'll understand that the `send` command is very useful.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct way to answer the question, as it seems I can't accept your comment as the answer. Please advise if there is a more acceptable way to mark your comment as the answer. It seems weird to mark my own question with your reply as the answer.

Comment: My reply is meant as a comment, not as an answer, because your question isn't a straightforward coding question. The answer is somewhat opinion-based and should therefore be posted as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: The code in the dictionary is actually a simple timer as it will drift in the long run... See my answer for explanation

Answer (score 0):

Ok Mark already answered but here goes:

You can use your code but need to use:

```
wait 1 second with messages
```

Then LiveCode will let other parts of the (LiveCode) system get some time to work, but your code will kind of halt anyway so it will be hard to perform other actions.

By using `send ... in [time]` your interface will not halt in any way. The screen will update accordingly, and all your handlers can go about and do their thing. As Mark wrote, send will queue if your app is busy doing something else. That implies that if you want to display a countdown, with lets say 10th of a second, you can't just set the interval to 100 milliseconds and then decrease the start value by 0.1. (As you can't be 100% sure that it will fire at the exact time, and on top of that your timer code might shave of a few milliseconds each run). Instead you need to check agains the milliseconds elapsed. Lets say you want to display the timer time with 0.1s precision in a field "Timer" you can have:

```
local lStartTime, lTimerTime

on startTimer pTimerTimeInSeconds
   put the milliseconds into lStartTime
   put lStartTime + pTimerTimeInSeconds * 1000 into lTimerTime
   runTimer
end startTimer

on runTimer
   put lTimerTime - the milliseconds into tTimeLeft
   put format("%.1f", tTimeLeft * 0.001) into field "Timer"
   if tTimeLeft > 0 then
      send "runTimer" to me in 100 milliseconds
   else
      put 0 into field "timer" # To ensure we don't get a negative number
   end if
end runTimer
```

By using `send ... in [time]` LiveCode will happily do other things even as the timer is running, and your timer will still count correctly. The final thing you need to cater for is if you do anything that might cause the code to stop working you need to cancel the next send. If you move on to another card your "runtimer" will still be called but when it tries to update the field there might not be a field at all. To handle that you might need to add some code. First you need a variable that will hold the id returned by the send command

```
local lStartTime, lTimerTime, lTimerID
```

then you need to save the id after calling send

```
...
send "runTimer" to me in 100 milliseconds
put the result into lTimerID
```

Then you can cancel the send if needed:

```
on cancelTimer
    cancel lTimerID
end cancelTimer
```

Comment: Hi hliljegren. Thank you very much for your detailed answer. If I move cards, couldn't I simply use "put 0 into field "timer" of card timerCard" instead, so that the correct field is updated?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... Yes, you can but you still need to cancel the timer.

Answer (score 0):

With the send command you have full control of your message queue (outside of ide) if you need it.  its very very useful, as you can basically control the engine at almost per millisecond level (more or less). whoever looks up this answer.  Its easy to learn the send command, but i wouldn't build anything without it.